# clang++ or g++ , which to choose for running c++ file on mac visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

What to choose from here:
[image: What to choose from here]

Options to run code:
[image: options to run code]

In the first image i am seeing many option to select, can anyone tell me what it is and what should i select?

this is a new device macbook air, i am new to programming, can you please suggest what shall i do or point me to resources. It would be really helpful

Comment: Which to choose? That depends entirely on which of those two compilers you have installed.

Comment: By default the commands `gcc` and `g++` are *aliases* for `clang` and `clang++` respectively. But if you install the actual GCC both are good. And actually, it's good to build your code with as many compilers as you can, since Clang can warn about some things that GCC doesn't, and GCC can warn about some things that Clang can't.

Comment: @SantoshKumarDoodala So since you don't have g++ installed and g++ is just an alias for clang++ (the two are quite similar) the sensible option would seem to be one of the clang++ options. Why you would prefer one or other of the two clang++ options I couldn't say. I expect both would work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use clang++ if you have clang compiler downloaded.
clang++ is praised for its strict adherence to standards and its quick adoption of new C++ features. It is known for providing more informative error messages and better diagnostics compared to g++.
g++ has historically been criticized for being less strict in its adherence to standards, but it has also made significant improvements in recent versions.